# Improve setting array as a key in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, object

I have the following issue. I need to set generated data in cache object. Data depends on array of ids. And if another array has the same ids but in other order we should give him value from cache.

So it works well when array have a not so huge length. But it takes much resources when `ids` contains thousands of items. My personal opinion that reason is in function `createKey` with calling `Array.sort()` function. Please, help me to improve algorithm of creating string key from array of ids.

```js
const cache = {};
const generateData = (ids) => ids.join('|'); // it doesn't matter
const createKey = (ids) => ids.sort().join(',');

const generateArray = (count) => Array.from(Array(count).keys());

const ids1 = generateArray(1000000);
const data1 = generateData(ids1);

const key1 = createKey(ids1);

cache[key1] = data1; // set value to cache

const ids2 = ids1.reverse();
const key2 = createKey(ids2);

const data2 = cache[key2]; // take value from cache

console.log(data2 === undefined);
console.log(data2 === data1); // it means that we use value from cache
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve]

Comment: Not sure how much you can improve it if the key needs to be in order.

Comment: @epascarello it's just my implementation. Personally I don't know how to create same keys from arrays with same values instead of `.sort().join(',')` Maybe you can provide me better way of creating key for cache object?

Comment: I doubt there is anyway to improve it if that is what you need.

Comment: @mplungjan I have added example. Thanks for creating template!

Comment: You need a hash function.

Comment: @Wyck can you provide an example?

Comment: How are you currently measuring that "it takes much resources"?

Comment: @Wyck check load graphs in AWS